# Yii2 prevent TimestampBehavior

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I am creating a custom Identity interface without created_at property. I got an error :

```
"name": "Unknown Property",
"message": "Setting unknown property: api\\common\\models\\User::created_at",
```

I tried to comment the TimestampBehavior, but I got the following error:

```
 "name": "PHP Warning",
 "message": "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()",
```

I want to know where is the problem.

Model class:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%user}}';
}

public function behaviors()
{
    // return [
    //     TimestampBehavior::className(),
    // ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['purpose'], 'required'],
        [['status'], 'integer'],

    ];
}

}
```

for the rest controller the action is

```
           public function actionLogin(){
                . 
                . 
                .

                $api_user = new User();
                $api_user->purpose="app";
                $api_user->status=User::STATUS_ACTIVE;
                if($api_user->save()){
                    $success = true;

                }
            }
```

Comment: Add your model code.

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve].

Comment: @Zainab Show your `controller` action and `view` form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `Behavior` in your `model` to:

```
public function behaviors()

{

    return [

        'timestamp' => [

            'class' => 'yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior',

            'attributes' => [

                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['updated_at'],

                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],

            ],

            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),

        ],           

    ];

 }
```

if you haven't `updated_at` also delete it from attributes.

Comment: I don't have updated_at. and still getting the same error.

Comment: @Zainab Ok. So remove `updated_at` from my answer. means like this `ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => [],ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => []`

Answer (score 1):

This will automatically resolve the issue. [BlameableBehavior](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-blameablebehavior) and [TimestampBehavior](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior)

```
// Include these on the start
use yii\behaviors\BlameableBehavior;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use Carbon\Carbon;

// Paste this function inside the class.

/**
     * @return array
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'blameable' => [
                'class'              => BlameableBehavior::className(),
                'createdByAttribute' => 'created_by',
                'updatedByAttribute' => 'updated_by',
            ],
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'createdAtAttribute' => 'created_at',
                'updatedAtAttribute' => 'updated_at',
                'value' => Carbon::now(),
            ],
        ];
    }
```

> NOTE: If you are not using `updated_at` or `updated_by` then remove it
>   form the above code

Answer (score 0):

You were getting following warning because you've completely removed the return in the `behaviors()` method.

> "name": "PHP Warning",
>
> "message": "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()",

The behaviors method must return an array. If you don't want to use any behavior your `behaviors()` method should return empty array like this:

```php
public function behaviors()
{
    return [];
}
```

This is also default implementation of `behaviors()` method in `yii\base\Component` so if you don't need to use any behavior you can simply remove the `behaviors()` method from your model.

Attaching `TimestampBehavior` to your model when you are not using it means that you add unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

**Example:** Rename and prevent time recording or remove properties. Also change the value

Rename or delete properties or change value.

```
public function behaviors()
{
  return [
    [
        'class' => \yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior::className(),
        'createdAtAttribute' => 'created_at',
        // 'createdAtAttribute' => 'c_time', //Change the name of the field
        'updatedAtAttribute' => false, //false if you do not want to record the creation time.
        // 'value' => new Expression('NOW()'), // Change the value
    ],
  ];
}
```

Or

```
      'class' => \yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior::className(),
      'attributes' => [
          \yii\db\ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at'],
          // \yii\db\ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => [],
      ],
```

> `$createdAtAttribute`: The attribute that will receive timestamp value Set this property to false if you do not want to record the creation time.
>
> `$attributes`: List of attributes that are to be automatically filled with the value specified via $value. The array keys are the ActiveRecord events upon which the attributes are to be updated, and the array values are the corresponding attribute(s) to be updated. You can use a string to represent a single attribute, or an array to represent a list of attributes. For example,
>
> ```
> [
>     ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['attribute1', 'attribute2'],
>     ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'attribute2',
> ]
> ```